# Duplicate class com.google.android.a.a found in modules?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack, install-referrer, android-jetifier

I tried adding Installreferrer to my app after adding it to gradle, when rebuilding the app. I'm getting this error.

`Duplicate class com.google.android.a.a found in modules jetified-installreferrer-2.2-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2) and jetified-payu-gpay-1.3.2-runtime (com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.3.2)`

`Duplicate class com.google.android.a.b found in modules jetified-installreferrer-2.2-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2) and jetified-payu-gpay-1.3.2-runtime (com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.3.2)`

`Duplicate class com.google.android.a.c found in modules jetified-installreferrer-2.2-runtime (com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2) and jetified-payu-gpay-1.3.2-runtime (com.payu.gpay:payu-gpay:1.3.2)`

Comment: facing same issue but didn't get solution

Comment: Try downgrading the version number to 2.1. This should resolve the issue.
`implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.1'`

Answer (score 1):

Downgrading the version number of library to 2.1 as mentioned in comment didn't help as I was getting the issue for FirebasePerformancePlugin too. So I believe other libraries too can have conflict.

Here is what I did.

1. Confirmed a.a.a exists by analyzing apk.

> Build > Analyze apk.

[image]

You can see there is a file a.a.a which is an empty interface which was clashing with the library.

2. Open mapping.txt file

> Auto generated build folder > output > mapping > prodRelease > mapping.txt

Search for a.a.a

[image]

3. Open the file which maps a.a.a. My case it was DataBindingComponent in androidx.databinding package

[image]

It is an interface which seems identical as in the first image represented by a.a.a

4. Exclude it on proguard

[image]

I don't know if it is a proper solution. Do rectify if there is any proper/ better solution.